# Will changes (disabling camera, microphone, etc) made on windows remain on linux?

Tags: linux, windows-10, multi-boot

does anyone know that if I made changes to something like charging thereshold and disabling camera on windows, will that apply to my linux system as well? Also, if I later on uninstall windows and only keep linux, will the change stay as it is? If so, is there anyway to permanently erase those traces left by windows and get me a clean clean linux?

Comment: No, they won't apply to Linux. You will need to make changes there as well.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any specific change made on windows that will be kept on linux? BIOS update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Depending on what exactly you do you either disable a (Windows) driver or a software switch in said driver.

There’s really only one kind of toggle that *sometimes* persists: Turning off radios (WiFi, Bluetooth, WWAN, …). There’s a Linux package to control these, `rfkill`.

On some devices, you can disable certain built-in hardware/features in the firmware setup. You may want to look into that.

Comment: So any change made to the hardware on windows is only relevent to windows? Is there any change that is shared by two operating systems? Like maybe BIOS?

Comment: If you make changes to the hardware, these changes will of course affect all OSs. For example, if you install a new RAM module, that module will not vanish into thin air as soon as you reboot. But you're not asking about making changes to the hardware. You are asking about changing some values in the Windows driver configuration.

Comment: Of course, if your system has a way of *physically* turning off the webcam, that will again affect all OSs. For example, some webcams have an off switch that will *literally* move a physical lid in front of the lens. This will make the camera unusable in all operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

Operating system-specific changes will be written to the registry, or a file only that the operating system version will be aware of.

e.g. If Windows 10 writes your preferences with respect to your webcam to a file in `%appdata%\local\`, your Ubuntu system will have no knowledge of the directory, let alone the files within it.

Any properties in the BIOS will be common to the boot-loader, such as boot order, as they're not operating system specific.

Comment: So since there's no way I can make changes to BIOS directly on windows, linux system will not be affected?